# Wanted: a way to change many keychain passwords simultaneously

Tags: macos, keychain

Problem: employer uses a common account (username and password) for numerous logins within their domain, and requires frequent password changes. Keychain can't seem to figure out that e.g. any subdomain of myemployer.com should use the same login and password, let alone any IP address within the relevant address block - and in any case, there are a few hold out internal sites that use different logins. So I have a *lot* of keychain entries referring to the same account/password pair - plus more still referring to the same account with past generation passwords.

What I want is to select all keychain items with a given username and old password, and change them all to same user name and new password, rather than playing whackamole as first my email access fails, then all the internal sites, one after another.

Even arranging to *see* extra detail of all accounts at once would help, saving time manually selecting each one to see whether it's affected by the latest mass change.

I'll happily write code to do this, if there's an API but no pre-programmed tool. Preferably in python, C or almost any scripting language, but I'm annoyed enough to consider using a language I don't know well.

Can anyone point me at ways of solving this problem?

Comment: I've searched but not found anything suitable. I do help maintain the [Python keyring](https://pypi.org/project/keyring) which [partially implements the macOS security API](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/blob/10.0.2/keyring/backends/_OS_X_API.py). It should be possible to build on that to implement a script for keychain passwords, although that won't help for iCloud passwords, which seem to use [this api](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1654440-shared_web_credentials). If I can help you implement something based on that work, feel free to file tickets at the Github project.